# Prove A is contained in B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose A and B are two sets with $(A \times B) \cup (B \times A) = A \times A$. Prove that $A ⊆ B$

How would i start the proof off?

I know that $A \times B = \{(a, b) | a ∈ A, b ∈ B\}$, would this help me?

Pick $x ∈ B$, what are the steps i take? Sorry i'm new to proofs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to show a set $A$ is contained in another set $B$, we take an arbitrary element $a\in A$ and show that $a$ must be contained in $B$ as well. Let's try.

If $a\in A$, then we know $(a, a)$ is contained in $A\times A$ by definition of the set product. Now we use the hypothesis that $A\times A= (A\times B)\cup (B\times A)$. In particular, every element in $A\times A$ is contained in $(A\times B)\cup (B\times A)$. By definition, this means $(a,a)\in A\times B$ or $(a,a)\in B\times A$ (or both). Can you finish from here?

Comment: would it be that since a ∈ A xB and A ∈ B x A, therefore A is contained in B

Comment: Not quite; the element $a$ is not contained in the set product, but the element $(a,a)$ is contained in the set product (the case in which it is contained in $B\times A$ is symmetric). By definition of the set product, this means the right coordinate must be contained in $B$, i.e. $a\in B$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For any element $$x\in{B}$$ and $$a\in{A}$$, $$(a,x)\in{A×B}$$                      $$\Rightarrow (a,x)\in{A×A} \Rightarrow x\in{A}$$. Thus all elements of $B$  are in $A$.

Comment: Sorry the other anwer added was not shown in my device while i added my answer.